# Request to enable GPS occuring twice if activity stopped and started again

Tags: android, gps

I have an activity which requests the user to enable the GPS in the onStart() by showing a dialog with OK and CANCEL buttons. But if the user presses home button before interacting with the dialog, and starts the app again, a new dialog box appears on top of the old one and hence the user sees two dialog boxes one after the another. How can I dismiss the old dialog box in the onStop method of the activity?

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    enableGPS();
}

private void enableGPS() {                                      //GPS ENABLE RELATED METHOD
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi
            .checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result
                    .getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:                           //GPS ALREDY TURNED ON
                    if (locationServiceConnected) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(enableGPSActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, enableGPSActivity.this);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        redirectStatus.setText("ERROR: Not able to connect to Location Service");
                        btnRetry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:               //GPS NOT ALREDY TURNED ON, SHOW TURN ON DIALOG
                    try {
                        status.startResolutionForResult(enableGPSActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS); //CREATING DIALOG FOR GPS TURN ON
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:       //GPS CANNOT BE TURNED ON
                    redirectStatus.setText("Permission Available, not able to enable GPS");
                    btnRetry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {             //GPS ENABLE RELATED METHOD, DIALOG FOR GPS TURN ON
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {                 // GPS TURN ON ACCEPTED
            if (locationServiceConnected) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(enableGPSActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    redirectStatus.setText("Please Wait. Fetching Your Current Location");
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, enableGPSActivity.this);
                }
            }
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {               //GPS TURN ON REJECTED
            redirectStatus.setText("Permission Available, GPS Off");
            btnRetry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `enableGPS();` into `onCreate()` instead of `onStart()`. 
because,

According to the life-cycle of an `Activity` - **When user pressed home button**, the current activity will goes in background *by calling - `onPause()` and `onStop()` method*. **When you resume the activity from Stack** - `Activity` will be resumed *by calling `onRestart()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()`*.

Answer (score 1):

```
  //  declares variables name 

        private AlertDialog gpsAlertDialog;
        private boolean  isGpsDialogShowing = false;
        private LocationManager manager;


      // check gps enable or not if enable than remove dialog else show gps enable dialog in onResume method


protected void onResume() 
        {          
    if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)&&!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                    ShowGpsDialog();
                } else {
                    removeGpsDialog();
                }


            }


 //   remove dialog on destroy activity 

    @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            removeGpsDialog();
        }


 //   method for show dialog for gps enable    


          private void ShowGpsDialog() {

                isGpsDialogShowing = true;
                AlertDialog.Builder gpsBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MainMenuDrawerActivity.this);
                gpsBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                gpsBuilder
                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_no_gps))
                        .setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_no_gps_messgae))
                        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.dialog_enable_gps),
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int which) {
                                        // continue with delete
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        removeGpsDialog();
                                    }
                                })

                        .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.dialog_exit),
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int which) {
                                        // do nothing
                                        removeGpsDialog();
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                });
                gpsAlertDialog = gpsBuilder.create();
                gpsAlertDialog.show();
            }



      //  method for remove gps dialog 


            private void removeGpsDialog() {
                if (gpsAlertDialog != null && gpsAlertDialog.isShowing()) {
                    gpsAlertDialog.dismiss();
                    isGpsDialogShowing = false;
                    gpsAlertDialog = null;

                }
            }
```